# Prevent child div from overflowing its parent container when resizing the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to utilize the existing answers related to this issue on here, but none have resolved my problem.

I have a bootstrap 3 image carousel, within that carousel container, there is fixed text. The problem is when a shrink the browser page, the text overflows outside its parent. Ive added position: 'relative' on the container class ('container'), but the text still overflows. Any suggestions on how to prevent this?

css:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.child-header {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

the image carousel:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="hero-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#hero-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#hero-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#hero-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img class="hero-image" src="/assets/1.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="hero-image" src="/assets/2.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="hero-image" src="/assets/3.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-header">
        <h1><i>Heading 1</i></h1>
        <h3>Some description here</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First your code is incorrect, you are missing a semicolon for top and transform, also you have a semicolon after } which is incorrect. Add position absolute to the header for absolute positioning in regard to the relative container.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.child-header {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit suggestions, the semicolons were just overlooked when pasting the code on here. As far as the solution of adding 'absolute' position to the child, it doesn't work. It still overflows the parent container when shrinking the window

Comment: Depending on your real code it will always do that, because of the font-size you've chosen. If it is just too big it will overflow. Depending on the image you could try to stretch the content to fit the header, but you would have to rebuild it a little to work with flex-boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `.child-header` to

```
.child-header {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: contents;
}
```

or

```
.child-header {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hide the overflow:

```
.child-header{overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: The question was about preventing an overflow, not hiding it